# GOOGLE APP + PHP MAIL() = SPAM for HOTMAIL

Tags: dns, gmail, spam, hotmail

my emails sent with php mail() command are considered as spam by hotmail.
I use google app.
My Mx records are :

```
Pref    Hostname    
0   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com  
5   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com 
5   ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com 
10  ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.com   
10  ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.com
```

My php code is :

```
    $to = "to_email@hotmail.com";

    $subject = "Subject";

    //headers and subject
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: <$support@my.com>\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .='Reply-To: '.$to.''."\n"; 
    $headers .= "X-Sender: <www.my.com>\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n";
            $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
    $headers .= "X-auth-smtp-user: support@my.com\n";
    $headers .= "X-abuse-contact: support@my.com\n";
    $headers .= "From: MyName <support@my.com>\r\n";



    $body .= "My text here here : <br />" .
             "" . "<br />" . "<br />" .
             "My Name";


    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Maybe I need to add :

1. a **MX record for mail.my.com**
2. a **A record** like **mail.my.com.  A   123.89.89.09**

Please help